# Error installing Google Chrome on Windows XP (on VirtualBox)

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, virtualbox, vmware-player

I am having some problems with my freshly installed Windows XP on VirtualBox. I tried installing Google Chrome on it, and the error I get is:

```
Google Update installation failed with error 0x80040890
```

It is genuine Windows <strike>with SP3</strike>*. I also tried using VMware player, but it has the same problem. When the same Windows is installed on a real machine, there is no problem. Any ideas what might be the cause?

EDIT: My apology, the version I downloaded from Microsoft seems to be without service packs, I didn't notice it right away. That is the problem probably.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try downloading the setup again, if that din't help then possibly, the reason could be  that, the XP VM is Running in Audit Mode. To fix this issue you need to modify your Windows Registry:

1. Click on Start, and then click Run. Type in regedit and click OK.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State`.
3. Right-click Registry Key and choose Modify. Delete value in the field and click OK.

Hopefully this should fix the problem.

*Edit: As you edited the question and said that you don't have SP3, firstly update to SP3, possibly via Windows Update.*

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ninite.com/ download an install for chrome and run that. When I get occasional installer fails, and the app is on ninite - their packaged installers just work.